# Error when setting 2D array to 2D array

Tags: c++

I have this constructor:

```
Transform::Transform( float matrix[4][4] )
{
    m = matrix;
}
```

And this class definition:

```
class Transform
{
    float m[4][4];
public:
    Transform();
    Transform(float matrix[4][4]);
```

But this does not compile.

What could be wrong?

Error   1   error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'float [][4]' to 'float [4][4]'  c:\Users\Josh\Documents\agui\trunk\src\Agui\Transform.cpp   75

Thanks

Comment: I'd recommend `std::array` if you can use it. It does assignment.

Comment: Arrays are not copyable in this manner. You need to copy the *contents* (either through indexed access or a memory-move algorithm like `std::copy()`, `memcpy()` or `memmove()`. Of course, belay all that and do what chris says above. Use your stdlib. Its whats for dinner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using c++11 try to change `float matrix[4][4]` to `std::array<std::array<float,4>,4>`

It is a mouthful, but it supports such operations that c arrays do not natively support.

You could do something like this to clean up the syntax.

```
typedef std::array<std::array<float,4>,4> Matrix;
```

Now you can do

```
Matrix myMatrix;
```

p.s If you are not using C++11, you could use `vector` instead of `array`. It is a little different from array, but adds more features as well, and after you set it up access is identical.

Comment: With a typedef so it isn't a mouthful.

Comment: @Pubby, It's C++11 anyway. `template<typename T> using array4 = std::array<T, 4>;` :) Depends on what changes when you use it, really.

Comment: @Pubby very true, I have added it

Answer (score 3):

Karthik's answer is excellent, alternatively,  you could also do...

```
  for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
  {
     for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
      {
         m[i][j] = matrix[i][j];
      }
  }
```

The principle is the same that WhozCraig mentioned in the comment.

Answer (score 1):

Even though you declare the parameter to your constructor as `float matrix[4][4]`, the compiler ignores the first `4`.

Comment: I guess then it sees it as float*[4]

Comment: @Milo You will need to ask a language Nazi for the difference between `float [][4]` (as in your error message) and `float *[4]`. I typically treat them as the same thing (which probably isn't technically accurate).

Comment: Not a lang-nazi, but so you know , `float(*)[4]`. With a variable decl it would be `float (*ar)[4]`. And its the *first* dimension (the superior dim) that is ignored; *not* all but the last. The sub-dimensions are used to calculate linear offset into the backdrop of the memory behind the array.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks for the clarification. I removed that sentence from my answer.